# Cloudstack installation/configuration using CLI

Tags: cloud, cluster-computing, virtualization

I am trying to install Cloudstack using the documentation. The installation process is fine, but I don't like the configuration process because they use GUi (their WebApp).

My question is: Is it possible to configure Cloudstack completely using just CLI and without using their WebApp?

Thanks